# React Native Text As Paragraphs

Tags: react-native

I am learning React Native for a project at work. I Need to display something like an article and I have dummy data in a JSON object as shown in the image. How do I break it into paragraphs so that it doesn't show just one big block of text?

I have a component with the code below;

```
<View  style={{ marginVertical: SIZES.extraLarge}}>
    <Text style={{fontSize:SIZES.large, textAlign:'justify', }}>{data.description</Text>
  </View>
```

[image]

Comment: Do you have control over the source? If so, you can put two new lines where you want paragraphs to end. Otherwise you have to make arbitrary assumptions (split at every "dot space", or splitting at every  2/3 dots ^^

Comment: The file with the data is part of my project files. It is a JS file with JSON data.

Comment: Do you have control on the data input as well? If so, let them write text in markdown / let them put line breaks where they need. Otherwise you have to manually manipulate the description field as suggested above.